# Is there a XML tag to add a label on an element in SVG?

Tags: xml, svg, tags

Is there a XML tag to add a label on an element in a SVG image ? Something like `label`. I don't manage to find it in documentation.

Comment: Do you mean the `xml:id` attribute?

Comment: Is `xml:id` visible on the rendered svg ? Like a toggle

Comment: Who said SVG? I don't see it mentioned anywhere nor tagged.

Comment: You can add comments to xml file.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to say it's SVG...

Comment: It would show a tooltip like a <title> yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, it's a `<title>` element. You add it as a child element and it [displays a tooltip](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements) containing the text content of the title. E.g.

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue">
    <title>something</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work. Actually `<title>` changes the title of the document so when I open it in a web browser, the name of the tab is `something`

Comment: Title on the root element does that too. The example above works for me i.e. displays a tooltip on both Chrome and Firefox.